# check if user is logged in in user control Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls

how can i check if a user is logged in in user control with asp.net mvc

usually on a view page i use this

```
<% if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {%>
  //Do something
<% } %>
```

but i can't get this done on a user control

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<%= Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>
```

Comment: Or try `<%= Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated %>`

Answer (score 73):

Nothing new to add to Griegs answer, but I would normally do

```
@Request.IsAuthenticated
```

Comment: Looking at the reference sources for `HttpRequestWrapper` and then `HttpRequest` the `IsAuthenticated` property is implemented with `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, among other things. `return(_context.User != null && _context.User.Identity != null && _context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);`

Comment: So what's the difference? Or are these two identical?

Comment: Pretty much. Mine is shorter. :-)

Answer (score 9):

You could decorate the Method with the [Authorize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute. This requires that the User calling the Method being authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I use VB

```
If User.Identity.Name = "" Then
   Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
Else
   ........continue...........
End If
```

Comment: As the original question did not have access to `User`, how would this make any difference "in a user control". Your example is in a controller and not a user-control. -1