# How to check if user is authorized inside Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, authorization

Usually I protect my Actions with `[Authorize]` but this time I need to check if a user is authorized inside the action.

Eg

```
if(userIsAuthorized) {
    //do stuff
}
else {
    //return to login page
}
```

<strike>I believe</strike> I am using 'Forms Authentication'

This question is kind of similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332132/check-if-user-is-logged-in-in-user-control-asp-net-mvc) but none of the answers given seemed to work.

EDIT: I have done some more digging- it seems if I breakpoint on an Action that has `[Authorize]`, the User.Identity is set, but on Actions without it, the User.Identity is empty, even if I am logged in

Comment: I have fixed my issue by using a hack-ish workaround, I am going to assume your answers are all correct and it is due to my strange implementation of authentication that things are strange...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you just want to know if the user is logged in:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { ... }
```

If you are trying to do anything role-specific:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Administrators")) { ... }
```

The `User` instance is a public property of the `Controller` class, so you always have access to it from a Controller you write.  If no user is logged in you should have a `GenericPrincipal` for the `User` and a `GenericIdentity` for the `User.Identity`, so don't worry about checking for nulls.

Comment: Again, only gives me 'true' if used within an `[Authorize]`'d Action

Comment: @elwyn: I don't believe that's correct.  I just tested it here on an action without the `[Authorize]` attribute and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `true`.  Are you sure that the session is actually logged in when you are testing this?

Comment: @Aaronaught Yes, just double (triple) checked, definantly logged in while trying that, and still see false

Comment: -----In my non-[Authorize]'d Action:
User.Identity
{System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity}
    [System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity]: {System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity}
    AuthenticationType: ""
    IsAuthenticated: false
    Name: ""

-----In an Authorized one:
User.Identity
{System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity}
    [System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity]: {System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity}
    AuthenticationType: "Forms"
    IsAuthenticated: true
    Name: "admin"

Comment: @elwyin: Nothing I can do reproduces the behaviour that you seem to be seeing.  You do not need the `[Authorize]` attribute for `User` and `User.Identity` to be valid.  Do you have any other attributes on the Controller?  Have you tried doing this in a new, clean MVC project, to make sure that nothing else in your app is interfering?

Answer (score 6):

`Request.IsAuthenticated` should work for what you're trying to do.

Comment: If I do that on an Action decorated with `[Authorize]` it works fine, however if I do that on this Action (not decorated with [Authorize]) it is always false, regardless of whether I am logged in or not.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first figuring out what kind of Authorization your using. ;)

The answer you posted is correct.  From what I remember poking around the [Authorize] attribute and related ActionFilter code MVC internally calls Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated just like those code examples.

Comment: Double checked and it is Forms Authentication

Answer (score 1):

Create an attribute like this: OnActionExecuting will get executed first before other code from the action

```
     public class IsAuthenticatedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
               //do your validations here. and redirect to somewhere if needed. 
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/") //this will send user to home.
            }
        }
```

on each action where you need to check, add attribute like this:

```
[IsAuthenticatedAttribute]
public ActionResult ActionName(parameters?)
{
     // no need to worry about checking here.
    //do you action things
}
```

**EDIT:**
This one still completes the action and then only redirect it. Not so much useful.

Answer (score 0):

Put annotation [Authorize] in every your Action.
[Microsoft link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
Example:

```
public class AdministrationController : Controller
{
     // GET: User/Create
       [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Create()
        { 
     }
}
```