# How to block access to the page when typing URL directly in the browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with a number of pages.
I'm trying to authenticate the user before opening a page.

I have created a Login page that works and authorizing a user.

However, when I enter the page URL directly in the browser, I'm able to open it.

How can I restrict the user from opening the page directly?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Do you have a construct in the Controller class that renders the Views? If so, you could check for a authenticated session inside the construct  (or inside the function that renders a page view), and if there isn't one, route them to the login page.

Comment: I'm using C#. I tried to use [Authorize] Attribute before every controller and  looks like it is working

Comment: Don't know if this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204766/how-to-check-if-user-is-authorized-inside-action